# controlling the order in which mysql database entries are saved

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having this problem where my points are not saving in the correct order. 
In my javascript I have the following code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++)
{       
    //save first point with newLine set to true
    loadJSON(currentServer + "?action=setAnnotCoord" + "&pic=" + CurrentImage
    +'&pid=' + pid + '&xCoord=' + coordArray[i][0] + '&newLine=true &drawingColor=' + lineColor[i]);

    //rest of the points with newLine set to false
    for(var j = 1; j < coordArray[i].length; j++)
    {
        loadJSON(currentServer + "?action=setAnnotCoord" + "&pic=" + CurrentImage
        +'&pid=' + pid + '&coord=' + coordArray[i][j] + '&newLine=false &drawingColor=' + lineColor[i]);
    }           
}
```

The loadJSON() method basically takes me to my php script with the passed parameters sent as a GET request. The php code looks like this:

```
if($action == 'setAnnotCoord' && $userIDSet && $pidSet && $picSet)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cbmarker.annot_test (userid, project_id, image, date, coords, newLine, color)
            VALUES (" . $userID . "," . $pid . ",'". $pic . "', NOW()," . $coord . "," . $newLine . ",'" . $drawingColor . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

The entries do correctly save to the database but sometimes they will switch the order in which they enter which ruins my intended coordinate data. The data is suppose to alternate between x and y coordinates. So say I pass in the entries for coordinates 1, 5, 10, and 12. I want my coordinate pairs to be [1, 5] and [10, 12]. However, when the entries are written to the database, an example of the order they might be written is 1, 5, 12, 10 as opposed to what I originally intended so that my coordinate pairs now become [1, 5] and [12, 10]. I can't figure out how to get them to write in the correct order but based on my research, I'm thinking the problem may be due to a race condition. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know they are not in the right order? By looking at the data in the table, or some other way?

Comment: Yes, I manually look at the data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `loadJSON` function does work asynchronously.

Change it, so it queues the GET/POST requests so the order stays correct, and your problem is solved.

Comment: I believe I am doing that. Here's a line in my loadJSON() method:

function loadJSON(url,action) 
{
  actionArray[movementCounter] = {"action":action,"url":url,"move":movementCounter,"attempt":attempt,"complete":false,"errors":"","date":d.toUTCString()};

Answer (score 0):

When you load a web page, it loads the HTML and then the images. You have very little idea and absolutely no guarantee in which order those images will be requested, process and arrive from the server (or even *if*).

That is the nature of asynchronous communications. You also have no guarantee what order rows will be returned from the database unless a sort order is specified.

I would suggest either sending them up in a block *or* including their position in the array as part of the row and using that to sort the results.

Comment: Though your issue is probably elsewhere... As a general rule, one should not rely on "entry order" in an RDBMS. Instead, the table should have the info you need to figure out the order. If it means you need a sequence number field, then so be it.